# Условия LDAP запроса

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

Парсил AD для благих целей и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой.

При указании в LDAP запросе "отобрать пользователей, УЗ которых не отключена" код не компилируется, ругается на условие **"!"** в `(!useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)`. Если логическое "НЕ" убрать, все отлично работает, но отключенные пользователи нас не интересуют. В AD запрос отрабатывает, что логично. Вариантов не использовать **"!"** нагуглить не удалось ...

Как решить данную проблему?

```
from re import split
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SIMPLE, SYNC, ASYNC, SUBTREE, ALL


AD_SERVER = ''
AD_USER = ''
AD_PASSWORD = ''
AD_SEARCH_TREE = ''

server = Server(AD_SERVER)
conn = Connection(server,user=AD_USER,password=AD_PASSWORD)
conn.bind()

conn.search(AD_SEARCH_TREE,'(&(objectCategory=User)(sAMAccountName=*)(sAMAccountType=805306368)**(!useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)**(employeeID=*))', SUBTREE,
    attributes = ['cn', 'title', 'department', 'division', 'employeeID', 'mail', 'sAMAccountName', 'manager', 'telephoneNumber']
            )

data = conn.entries

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    print(
        data[i]['cn'], ',' ,
        data[i]['title'], ',' , 
        data[i]['department'], ',' , 
        data[i]['division'], ',' , 
        data[i]['employeeID'], ',' , 
        data[i]['mail'], ',' , 
        data[i]['sAMAccountName'], ',' ,
        #((data[i]['manager'][0].split(',OU')[:1])), ',' ,
        #(''.join((data[i]['manager'][0].split(',OU')[:1])[0].split('CN=')[1:])), ',' , 
        data[i]['telephoneNumber']
        )
```

Comment: Нет понимания как туда его подставлять) Да и не уверен, что LDAP поддерживает "NOT". Но могу ошибаться)

Comment: Поглядел документацию. Там для отрицания условие в обязательном порядке оборачивается. Т.е. `(!(useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))` - попробуй.

Comment: Почти одновременно пришли к верному ответу) только Вы через документацию, я методом тыка, как пологает новичку)
Благодарю!

Comment: А напишите самоответ. Разберите причину проблемы, сошлитесь на доку (https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html  и https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searches.html, может что ещё) - и для себя полезно, и может ещё кому-то помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Для отрицания в ldap3, в обязательном порядке требуется экранирование условия скобками:

```
(!(useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```

Благодарю за подсказку: [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) и наводку на [Документацию](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searches.html)